# Get child view size within onMeasure

Tags: android, android-layout

I have listView with items created dynamicaly.Each item is my custom view and contains(from top to bottom) header,imageView and footer.I set item's height in the onMeasure method.I'd like imageView's height to be exactly

```
 image_height=item_height-(footer_height+header_height)
```

I set footer/header height in the xml(constant value)
However when I try to get footer/header height it returns 0

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthSpec,heightSpec);
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    //float ar=896f/768f;
    int itemWidth=widthSize/IMGS_PER_ROW;
    int calculated_width =widthSize;
    int calculated_height = (int) (itemWidth*(1/IMG_ASPECT_RATIO));
    if(!initialized) {
        Image img=new Image(this.getContext());
        int dy=((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.separator)).getHeight();//returns 0
        Log.d("item",calculated_width+","+calculated_height+","+dy);
        initialized=true;
    }
    this.setMeasuredDimension(calculated_width, calculated_height);
}
```

Item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.rhyboo.net.listtest.ListItemView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:text="Title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/items_container"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
 </com.rhyboo.net.listtest.ListItemView>
```

Comment: Try to the change the imageView height in the onDraw method. By the time the view is going to be draw the height will be different of 0 (unless you set 0).

Comment: I've overrided onDraw but its never gets called although I set `this.setWillNotDraw(false);` in the constructor and I can see my list items on the screen but onDraw isn't called

Comment: onMeasure is not called in view groups. Are you overriding onMeasure in the ListItemView or the ListView?

Comment: I override it within my item's view which is custom view inherited from FrameLayout

Comment: FrameLayout is a view group, so onDraw is not going to be called, my mistake. Use dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas).

Comment: Yeah I just changed base type to LinearLayout and now I'm getting non zero values for header/footer height.Thanks!